# How to tag a friend, while post on wall using facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I need the key which specifies a friends that can be taged in a post (facebook)

```
if (session.isOpened()) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, "publish_actions");
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }

Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), "Join me", new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                showPublishResult("Result", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            }
        });

        Bundle params = request.getParameters();
        params.putString("message", "hello test 10");
        params.putStringArray("tags", new String[]{id});
        request.setParameters(params);

        request.executeAsync();
```

The above code only posts on facebook wall without taging the friend whose  'ID' is passed.

Is there any solution for taging my friend in the post on the facebook wall

Please suggest if anything wrong in the above code

I have tried "tags", "with_tag","tag","to" but nothing seems working.
This is the link from were I have read all the doc [facebook dev doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post) 
can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a place in order to use tags.  From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed

> tags: Comma-separated list of user IDs of people tagged in this post. You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

Comment: … and that you should only do, if the user is actually at the physical location together with the person they are tagging.